# has anyone used influxdb cli?

Tags: database, command-line-interface

I am not able to install it. Following error occurred while instilling.

```
testing@testing-VirtualBox:~$ npm install influxdb-cli -g

 npm http GET registry.npmjs.org/influxdb-cli

 npm http GET registry.npmjs.org/influxdb-cli

 npm http 304 registry.npmjs.org/influxdb-cli

 npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/influxdb-cli'

 npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/influxdb-cli']

 npm ERR!   errno: 3,

npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/influxdb-cli',

npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',

npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/influxdb-cli',

npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',

npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 

npm ERR!    [ '/usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',

npm ERR!      '/usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:51:17',

npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.


npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-12-generic

npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "influxdb-cli" "-g"

npm ERR! cwd /home/testing

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15

npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/influxdb-cli

npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/influxdb-cli

npm ERR! fstream_type Directory

npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/influxdb-cli'

npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23

npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/lib/nodejs/mkdirp/index.js:51:17

npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/testing/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use sudo when specifying the -g flag as answered here: [npm install failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964173/npm-install-failing)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sudo is required also nodejs 10.0+ should be installed before calling this command.

npm install influxdb-cli -g

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` should fix your problem `sudo npm install influxdb-cli -g`, but it isn't mandatory to use `sudo` in order to install node package binaries, you can follow these instructions: ["set a local node prefix"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18277225/464685):

```
echo prefix = ~/.node >> ~/.npmrc

export $PATH=$HOME/.node/bin:$PATH
```

to install node packages in your home directory without requiring `/usr/` permissions.

I created a [ruby influxdb-cli](https://github.com/phstc/influxdb-cli), which uses ruby instead of node. Besides the InfluxDB Query Language, it also supports InfluxDB API calls through `db` variable.

`gem install influxdb-cli`.

The Getting Started Guide is available on GitHub:

https://github.com/phstc/influxdb-cli